# how to resolve error while running image_to_string(img)

Tags: ocr

I am getting error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

The system cannot find the file specified error while running `img = Image.open('temp1.jpg')`

```
text = image_to_string(img)
```

Comment: What language are you using? What OCR solution are you using? It is quite hard to provide an answer given this much information.

Comment: I am using python 2.7